# Unable to install pycrytpo

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to upgrade pycryto from 2.4.1 to 2.7.1 using below command,for some reason it says the installation is already there but its an old version,
can anyone provide inputs on how this can be done?

```
 sudo pip install pycrypto
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade pycrypto
```

you could refer here: [pip docs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#non-recursive-upgrades)